# Rings with same quotient field

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $R$ be an integral domain and $0 \neq I$ an ideal of $R$. Denote by $\phi: R \rightarrow R/I$ the canonical homomorphism. Let $S$ be a subring of $R/I$ such that $R/I$ is integral over $S$. Suppose $T=\phi^{-1}(S)$. Is it true that the quotient field of $T$ is the same as the quotient field of $R$? I do not know to prove or to disprove the claim. I know it is true if $R \subset Quot(T)$, where $Quot(T)$ is the quotient field of $T$, but I do not think this is true in general.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by what $\phi^{-1}(S)$ means. The morphism $\phi$ is an $R$-homomorphism, but $S$ is not an $R$-submodule of $R/I$ unless $S = R/I$. For instance, if $R = k[x,y]$ and $I = (y)$, then $k$ and $k[x]$ is a subring of $R/I$. What should be $\phi^{-1}(k)$ and $\phi^{-1}(k[x])$?

Comment: The pre-image of a subring with respect to a ring homomorphism is a subring.

Comment: With $R = k[x,y]$ and $I=(y)$, $\phi^{-1}(k)$ is the subring of $R$, that consists of all polynomials which have no monomial containing $x$ but not $y$.

Funny side remark: This a non-noetherian subring of $R$.

Comment: @FrankZermelo As you were told, no need to suppose $S\subset R/I$ integral in order to get $Q(T)=Q(R)$, but under this extra-condition you have $T\subset R$ integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do not need the integral assumption:

Take $0 \neq f \in I$. We have $\phi(rf)=0 \in S$, hence $rf \in T$ for all $r \in R$. In particular $f \in T$. Now we have $r = \frac{rf}{f} \in Quot(T)$, which shows $R \subset Quot(T)$, which is literally all we need.

Comment: Many thanks! I totally missed this trick.